# Unity Bootstrapper my configure container does not work when call a View Model

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, unity-container, prism

I use prism 6.1. I set up the Unity configuration in the method `ConfigureContainer` of `Bootstrapper` class. But, when the Prism framework try to call the View Model, it can't create this, and throw the exception 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object.'.

Bootstrapper.cs

```
public class Bootstrapper: UnityBootstrapper
{
    ...
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        this.Container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
        this.Container.RegisterType<MyFormViewModel>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }
    ...
}
```

MyFormModule.cs

```
public class MyFormModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionViewRegistry regionViewRegistry;

    public SkypeActionModule(IRegionViewRegistry registry)
    {
        this.regionViewRegistry = registry;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(Views.MyFormView));
    }
}
```

MyFormViewModel.cs

```
public class MyFormViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private readonly IMyService myService;

    public SkypeActionViewModel(IMyService myService)
    {
        this.myService = myService;
    }
    ...
}
```

In this line throw the exception:

```
regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(Views.MyFormView));
```

In the [prism documentation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/20-ManagingDependenciesBetweenComponents.md#resolving-instances-with-unity) explains how to configurate unity, but this is in the Module class (in my case is `MyFormModule`). I don't understand that because in this way, I need to configurate that in each module, and I haven't the object `this.container.RegisterType` in my module class.

In others links, I found some configuration similar to "MEF" configuration, where the "DI" configuration are in the `ConfigureContainer` method. But it doesn't work for my, or something missing in my configuration.

**Edit**
I include the container in my module class. But I have the same problem. I suppose that is normal, because the problem is when Prism create the view model class `MyFormViewModel`.

```
public class MyFormModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionViewRegistry regionViewRegistry;

    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

    public MyFormModule(IRegionViewRegistry registry, IUnityContainer container)
    {
        this.regionViewRegistry = registry;

        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.container.RegisterType<IMyService, MyService>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        this.container.RegisterType<MyFormViewModel>();

        this.container.RegisterType<MyFormView>();

        regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(MyFormView));
    }
}
```

**Edit**

**Solution**: I found the solution in [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37045539/138071)

Create the method `BindViewModelToView` on `Bootstrap` class:

```
public void BindViewModelToView<TViewModel, TView>()
{
    ViewModelLocationProvider.Register(typeof(TView).ToString(), () => Container.Resolve<TViewModel>());
}
```

and then, in the method `ConfigureViewModelLocator` in `Bootstrap` class call all view models it to bind with views:

```
protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
{
    BindViewModelToView<ViewAVM, ViewA>();
    BindViewModelToView<ViewAVM, ViewB>();
}
```

Comment: You can have the container injected into the module definition class like any other dependency, so your module can call `container.RegisterType` like the bootstrapper. Same for the `IRegionManager`...

Comment: @Haukinger I include a `IUnityContainer` in my Module class, but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

How do you tell prism to create the view model? Are you using `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`?

If so, you want to do something like

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory( type =>
{
    return Container.Resolve(type);
});
```

in the bootstrapper to make sure that your container is used for resolving the view model...

Comment: I'm not using `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`. But I  found the solution. I will create a answer.

Comment: sorry, yes, I'm using `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` in my XAML file